# How to store the data from the html form to other page with out loosing it after page refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form which includes user details [name,Email and phone number].I need to store the form data into the html table.But the issue is the data is not getting stored permanently(i.e loosing the data after page refresh).

How to make the data persistant in the html table even after page refresh using jquery and ajax.

Comment: You have to save the data somewhere. Storing in html won't work. You have to save in a DB

Comment: How to store the data in the database using jquery in wordpress

Comment: Send an ajax to a php function, then save data to options table. Return to ajax.

Comment: could you please show it with example

Comment: $next_btn.on('click', function(e, force_update_customer) {

      console.log(jQuery('.bookly-js-full-name').val());
      console.log(jQuery('.bookly-js-user-phone-input').val());
      console.log(jQuery('.bookly-js-user-email').val());}  [this is my jquery code currently Iam outputing the form data fields to the console] . I am getting idea how to proceed further to store this data into the database and display it in the page. could you please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$next_btn.on('click', function(e, force_update_customer) {
      var form = $('#form_name'); // Your form id here
      var formdata = form.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxurl, // Refer sending ajax from wordpress to change here
            data: formdata,
            success: function(data) {
                 alert('success');
            }
        });
 });
```

This is just a a basic code to help you. You should change the code according to your requirements. You have to change ajaxurl according to your needs. You also have to refer sending ajax via wordpress

Comment: I dont have form and I have the data which is stored in the javascript variable.Now I want to store that javascript variable data to the database in wordpress or is it possible to store the data in the excel sheet (the only thing i want to store the data permanently)

Comment: Better to wrap these input fields into a form. Or you can take each input fields value to array and and pass this array to php funciton as in the above example.